# Javascript Debounce function misunderstand

Tags: javascript

In a course , the instructor wrote that debounce function :

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timeId;
    return (...args) => {
        if(timeId) clearTimeout(timeId);
        timeId = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(null, args)
        }, delay)
    }
}
```

to use it in event listener like that

```
input.addEventListener('input', debounce(onInput, 1000))
```

I think with every input we would reassign timeId to undefined which would make clearTimeout not working
but it does work , How ??

Comment: Add in some `console.log`s to see when the different parts of the code run. `debounce` is a *higher-order function*, it *returns* a function. You can think of it as an event listener factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debounce()` is only called once, when the event listener is added. It returns a closure that uses the same `timeId` variable every time it's called. So the variable isn't reset to `undefined` on every input.

You would be correct if it were written like:

```
input.addEventListener('input', function() { debounce(onInput, 1000); })
```

This would call `debounce()` on every input, which would create a new `timeId` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer is correct but there is a simpler way of doing that using the `bind` function:

```
input.addEventListener('input', debounce.bind(window, onInput, 1000))
```

The `window` at the start is the `thisArg`, the value of `this` in the function.